# SonarQube Server not starting while Jenkins tries to build the project

Tags: maven, jenkins, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I am using Jenkins 2.2 and Tomcat 8.0.36 for deploying the project (In Ubuntu 14.04) .
Within jenkins I provided the maven goals as sonar:sonar
While building I am getting following error

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.0.2:sonar (default-cli) on project MYPROJECTNAME: Unable to execute SonarQube: Fail to download libraries from server: Status returned by url [http://localhost:9000/batch/index] is not valid: [404] -> [Help 1]
Build step 'Invoke top-level Maven targets' marked build as failure
Injecting SonarQube environment variables using the configuration: SonarQube
An attempt to send an e-mail to empty list of recipients, ignored.
Finished: FAILURE

Give me some idea to over come this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`localhost:9000` is the default SonarQube url. It looks like you haven't properly filled in the Global-level configuration to point to your SonarQube server.